# Symfony 1.4: email configuration

Tags: php, email, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to simply send an email from my server running **Symfony 1.4**.

I have the usual basic mail server setup, with the server name `mail.tixxit.com.au` and port `25`. I have this configuration in my `factories.xml`:

```
  mailer:
    param:
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
          param:
            host:       mail.tixxit.com.au
            port:       25
            encryption: ssl # Not sure on this but have tried "tls" too
            username:   myaccount@tixxit.com.au
            password:   mypassword
```

Then I have a basic bit of send code in one of my actions:

```
        $this->getMailer()->composeAndSend(
            "myaccount@tixxit.com.au",
            "anotheraccount@gmail.com",
            "Message title",
            "Message content"
        );
```

From my what I've seen mentioned in other documentation, this should be all I need to do to send email from my server using **Symfony** in PHP, but this is not working. The send code does not give any errors, I can hit the `mail.tixxit.com.au` server from my web server fine, my credentials are definitely correct, and I have confirmed with support from my email hosting company that this should work and no configuration is required on their side to allow this.

But my mail isn't being sent. I have tried a whole lot of different settings in `factories.xml` but nothing works. It appears to send, but nothing ever arrives at `anotheraccount@gmail.com`. I have tried this on my local machine and my web server and get the same result.

What am I missing here? What `Symfony/PHP/server/mail` account settings do I need to actually make this work? Is there some fundamental other configuration that I am supposed to have set before the **Symfony** stuff that will allow me to send?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to this. Nothing seemed to work. I gave up and used the natural Swift classes e.g.:

```
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.tixxit.com.au', 25)
            ->setUsername('myaccount@tixxit.com.au')->setPassword('mypassword');

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Message title")
            ->setFrom(array('myaccount@tixxit.com.au' => 'App'))
            ->setTo(array('anotheraccount@gmail.com'));

        $message->setBody("Message content.");

        if ($mailer->send($message, $errors)) {
            $success = true;
        }
```